# Latex script in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, legend, axis-labels

I wish to use latex script $\theta$ for labelling the axes and legends in matplotlib figure. So I use the following piece of code.

```
y = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200)
plt.plot(y, np.sin(y)*np.cos(y), lw=3, label='$sin(\theta) cos(\theta)$')

plt.xlabel('$\theta$', fontsize=40)
plt.ylabel('$P(\theta,t)$', fontsize=40)
```

But this does not work and returns the following figure
[image]

The code works for $\Theta$, but I don't want to change the variable name. The same problem occurs with $\rho$, $\tau$, $\alpha$, $\beta$. Please give some tips on how to get out of this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use raw strings, otherwise the `\t` in your strings will be interpreted as  `TAB`.

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a
>   letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat
>   backslashes as literal characters.

You should generally do that for strings containing Latex expressions, as they very often contain backslashes.

```
y = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200)
plt.plot(y, np.sin(y)*np.cos(y), lw=3, label=r'$sin(\theta) cos(\theta)$')

plt.xlabel(r'$\theta$', fontsize=40)
plt.ylabel(r'$P(\theta,t)$', fontsize=40)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, simply escape the character so it's not interpreted as a tab.

```py
y = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200)
plt.plot(y, np.sin(y)*np.cos(y), lw=3, label='$sin(\\theta) cos(\\theta)$')

plt.xlabel('$\\theta$', fontsize=40)
plt.ylabel('$P(\\theta,t)$', fontsize=40)
```

NB: Show the legend/label as well

```py
plt.legend()
```

[image]